# How to point defferent domains to web modules in ONE ear project in glassfish?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, web, glassfish

I am working on an SNS program which I plan to develop with JavaEE technology with eclipse IDE, Glassfish server. To do this, I have a eclipse EAR project with structure of this:

- *xyz*, Enterprise Application Project, which packs up other modules bellow
- *xyz.jpa*, JPA project, the model layer
- *xyz.ejb*, EJB project, the data control layer
- *xyz.api*, Dynamic Web Project, the APIs used by mobile clients
- *xyz.www*, Dynamic Web Project, as a website
- *xyz.admin*, Dynamic Web Project, a web console for administration

These modules distribute as a deployable archive file *xyz.ear*. Each of the 3 web modules in this EAR should have its own domain(http://api.xyz.com -> *xyz.ap*i, http://www.xyz.com -> *xyz.www*, https://admin.xyz.com -> *xyz.admin*).

How do i do that? Or what will you do with this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, Glassfish's virtual server feature just fit my needs. I've not been developing Java Web programs so long that I forgot this, now it's all good.

I'd still like to see how do you design it.